# I'm being scraped, how can I prevent this?

Tags: iis-7, web-scraping

Running IIS 7, a couple of times a week I see a huge number of hits on Google Analytics from one geographical location.  The sequence of urls they are viewing are clearly being generated by some algorithm so I know I'm being scraped for content.  Is there any way to prevent this?  So frustrated that Google doesn't just give me an IP.

Comment: Off topic for SO.  They coming from Samara Oblast?  I'm getting slammed by somebody out that way...

Comment: Nope, continental US

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are plenty of techniques in the anti-scraping world. I'd just categorize them. If you find something missing in my answer please comment.

## A. Server side filtering based on web requests

### 1. Blocking suspicious IP or IPs.

The blocking suspicious IPs works well but today most of scraping is done using IP proxying so for a long run it wouldn't be effective. In your case you get requests from the same IP geo location, so if you ban this IP, the scrapers will surely leverage IP proxying thus staying IP independent and undetected.

### 2. Using DNS level filtering

Using DNS firewall pertains to the anti-scrape measure. Shortly saying this is to set up you web service to a private domain name servers (DNS) network that will filter and prevent bad requests before they reach your server. This sophisticated  measure is provided by some companies for complex website protection and you might get deeper in viewing [an example](http://webscraping.pro/scrapeshield-limited-feature-anti-content-duplicate-tool/) of such a service.

### 3. Have custom script to track users' statistic and drop troublesome requests

As you've mentioned you've detected an algorithm a scraper crawls urls. Have a custom script that tracks the request urls and based on this turns on protection measures. For this you have to activate a [shell] script in IIS. Side effect might be that the system response timing will increase, slowing down your services. By the way the algorithm that you've detected might be changed thus leaving this measure off.

### 4. Limit requests frequency

You might set a limitation of the frequency of requests or downloadable data amount. The restrictions must be applied considering the usability for a normal user. When compared to the scraper insistent requests you might set your web service rules to drop or delay unwanted activity. Yet if scraper gets reconfigured to imitate common user behaviour (thru some nowdays well-known tools: [Selenuim](http://webscraping.pro/what-is-selenium-webdriver/), Mechanize, [iMacros](http://webscraping.pro/data-extraction-using-imacros-plugin-for-ie/)) this measure will fail off.

### 5. Setting maximum session length

This measure is a good one but usually modern scrapers do perform session authentication thus cutting off session time is not that effective.

## B. Browser based identification and preventing

### 1. Set CAPTCHAs for target pages

This is the old times technique that for most part does solve scraping issue. Yet, if your scraping opponent leverages any of [anti-captcha services](https://webscraping.pro/8-best-captcha-solving-services-and-tools/) this protection will most likely be off.

### 2. Injecting JavaScript logic into web service response

JavaScript code should arrive to client (user's browser or scraping server) prior to or along with requested html content. This code functions to count and return a certain value to the target server. Based on this test the html code might be malformed or might even be not sent to the requester, thus leaving malicious scrapers off. The logic might be placed in one or more JavaScript-loadable files. This JavaScript logic might be applied not just to the whole content but also to only certain parts of site's content (ex. prices). To bypass this measure scrapers might need to turn to even [more complex scraping logic](http://webscraping.pro/javascript-protected-content-scrape/) (usually of JavaScript) that is highly customizable and thus costly.

## C. Content based protection

### 1. Disguising important data as images

This method of content protection is widely used today. It does prevent scrapers to collect data. Its side effect is that the data obfuscated as images are hidden for search engine indexing, thus downgrading site's SEO. If scrapers leverage a [OCR](https://webscraping.pro/8-best-captcha-solving-services-and-tools/#ocr) system this kind of protection is again might be bypassed.

### 2. Frequent page structure change

This is far effective way for scrape protection. It works not just to change elements *ids* and *classes* but the entire hierarchy. The latter involving styling restructuring thus imposing additional costs. Sure, the scraper side must adapt to a new structure if it wants to keep content scraping. Not much side effects if your service might afford it.

Comment: @Ryan, could you share of what particular part of my answer has helped you? Are you going to apply it? If already applied how much it has helped you? I ask you this since i do web scraping research and then post results into the *scraping.pro* blog. Any feedback will be appreciable!

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I've been restructuring html semi-regularly.  I wrote a scraper of my own, and I've just been doing my best to thwart all of my own attempts.  It's been more fun than it should be...

Comment: I see that this question was asked a few years and am wondering if IIS has changed because I am unable to scrape anything from one website while another site on the same IIS 10 server scrapes ok. I cannot find anything different in the config between the 2 sites.

Comment: @WilliamK, share these 2 sites and we'll check them. You better do it by commenting to the post https://webscraping.pro/my-site-is-being-scraped-how-can-i-prevent-being-scraped/

Comment: @Igor Savinkin - I did solve the problem by adding a user-agent so that it looked more human. Without that, IIS-10 prevented scrape by curl.