# Prevent bots from scraping our content / overloading our server

Tags: php, html, iframe, web-scraping, bots

We are planning to offer a job platform-service for some firms. We already have a few thousand jobs that we could offer to all our guest/visitors.

Since yesterday we noticed that our server-load is crazy and when we checked the logs we saw that we had multiple site-request per second from different IP addresses. However the order in which the pages were called indicate it was the same user / bot

We want to be available for the public but if bots are slowing our server massively down or forcing us for new hardware then we are in trouble.

We are currently displaying all our job-content in iframes, would an encoder like:
http://www.tareeinternet.com/scripts/iframe-encoder/

help to solve our problem?

Or what options do we have? Its especially annoying since we don't have user-sessions or recurring IP-Addreses (I think they are using proxys that switch regulary)

Comment: you could make a script, that blocks IPs when the do those kind of strange requests. That would at least force them to change proxys regularly and that might make them step back.

Comment: I guess you still want Google bot to be able to crawl your site, correct?

Comment: See my [expounded answer][1] to a similar question. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995620/im-being-scraped-how-can-i-prevent-this/29006465#29006465

Comment: Sounds like a job for psad https://cipherdyne.org/psad/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the headers for recurring data? If they, for example, have a recurring user-agent you can can block those:

- **Apache**:

```html
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Wget" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^EmailSiphon" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^EmailWolf" bad_bot
<Directory "/var/www">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Deny from env=bad_bot
</Directory>
```

- **Code**: You can check each requests for that specific header and redirect it to somewhere else.