# 'server replied: Forbidden' response error for images using phantomjs

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, poltergeist

I'm using phantomjs (2.0) to try and take a screenshot of the following website: http://www.langorigami.com/art/gallery/gallery.php?tag=birds&name=annas_hummingbird_3 but am getting the following errors for each image:

```
[DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: 202 ( "Error downloading http://www.langorigami.com/header/logo.gif - server replied: Forbidden" ) URL: "http://www.langorigami.com/header/logo.gif"
```

Any idea why and/or how to remedy?

Answer (score 1):

From the site's *Copyright & Usage* page:

> ...“the Content” are protected by copyright and are the property of Robert J. Lang unless specifically noted. This includes (but is not limited to) articles, text, photographs, images ...

Seems to me the site builders have taken care for anti-scrape measures. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995620/im-being-scraped-how-can-i-prevent-this/29006465#29006465) as to web-scraping protecting means.

Would you provide the essential scrape code you've already done?

Comment: Hi Igor, I'm actually just trying to create a screenshot of the page using a basic visit and render.